# Where should I keep data to continuously use in server?

Tags: server, backend

Currently, I'm trying to build a dating app(server part).

I'm going to store each user's profile data like videos, photos, profile messages to AWS S3.

And I have user info including location(longitude, latitude) in my database server.

If you've ever used this kind of app, you might easily understand how it works.

First, whenever a user opens this app, the user gets to see the profile of other users one at a time based on the current location.

Second, the user gives like or dislike to the current profile and gets to the next profile.

So, in order to implement the first step, I'm going to search other users in a certain distance from the user's current location in the database, but here I'm only going to get unique user ID values from database. This only happens once when a user opens the app.

Now that I have other users' id values like [id1, id2, id3, id4...] I can load each user's profile data from AWS S3 with each unique id value one by one whenever the user needs to see the next profile.

Here my question comes. To build the recommendation logic like that, where should I keep the id values??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "AWS S3" - S3 is for binary object storage. It is inappropriate for structured storage. Why aren't you using a relational database instead?

Comment: I would recommend you to use any in-memory cache or object storage, the reason why I am saying because the recommendation will change over time based on location.
Ideal case: In real work app like this, we do not store recommendation we do it on fly

Comment: @SuryaveerSingh You mean keep the list of unique ids ([id1, id2, id3 ...]) in in-memory cache and whenever the user needs to get the next profile, take the list from cache and load profile data from S3 with an id in the list, is that correct?? If so, i'm not sure if it's a good way to keep the list in in-memory cache because the more users I have, the bigger the list gets.

Comment: there are many stable in-memory server like Memcache and Redis, scalable and hight throuput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a in memory cache like Redis/memcache (both provided by AWS). Also your cahce should get updated as and when data in AWS S3 profile updates because only then you will have latest data.

Comment: I understand what you said, but is it a good way to keep that list of unique ids (ex [id1, id2, id3...]) in in memory cache? As I have more users the list may get bigger and bigger. I'm not sure about that..